# React-native picker with hooks typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I started studying react a short time ago and I did a project with select taking values ​​from an external api, it worked ok. When I went to react-native, to carry out the same project, I ended up getting stuck in the use of the picker, actually, with some control of the typescript.

Here is my code:

```
interface IBGEUFResponse {
  sigla: string;
}

interface IBGECityResponse {
  nome: string;
}

const Home = () => {
  const [ufs, setUfs] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [cities, setCities] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [selectedUf, setSelectedUf] = useState('');
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState('');
```

Here with some useEffect and control:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get<IBGEUFResponse[]>('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados?orderBy=nome')
    .then(response => {
      const ufInitials = response.data.map(uf => uf.sigla);

      setUfs(ufInitials);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(selectedUf === '') {
      return;
    }

    axios.get<IBGECityResponse[]>(`https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/${selectedUf}/municipios`)
    .then(response => {
      const cityNames = response.data.map(city => city.nome);

      setCities(cityNames);
    });
  }, [selectedUf]);
```

and finally the picker:

```
<Picker
            style={styles.input}
            selectedValue={selectedUf}
            onValueChange={newUf => setSelectedUf(newUf)}
          >
            {ufs.map(uf => {
           return (
           <Picker.Item key={uf} label={uf} value={uf}
            />
           );})}
```

So `setSelectedUf(newUf)` gets a (TS:2345) error in (newUf) and i can't see how to make it's work.

Sorry guys, but I spent a couple of days looking for solutions on the internet, adapting solutions for similar errors and I couldn't solve it.